# What are these weird IP address connections in resource monitor?

Tags: security, networking, monitoring

I decided to check out Resource Monitor (on the 'Performance' tab in Task Manager, Windows 7) and I noticed in the "Network" section that the 'System' image name kept making a bunch (~5 at a time) of connections to random IP addresses, it would show anywhere from 1-500 bytes/sec 'sent'. They would stay connected for 1-2 minutes.

-All web browsers are closed

So, the first thing I did was run a trace from network-tools.com on some of these IP addresses. 8/10 were outside of US and did not resolve to any host name. Of the 10 IP addresses I traced, 2 were in US, 4 showed origins in China, and one each to Algeria, Russia, Pakistan, Korea. (!)

So, the next thing I did was turn off my wireless card, watch the connections disappear, then turn the card back on, and within 30 seconds more random connections were created by System, with different IP addresses from the first time.

The next thing I did was go open Task Manager, Show Processes From All Users, then I killed just about everything that wasn't (what appeared to be) a Windows process.

I turned on Wi-Fi, and again within 30 seconds, random IP addresses connect for ~ 1 min at a time, new ones coming and going.

I occasionally use BitTorrent on this machine, but there was definitely no process that seemed related to BitTorrent running after I went through Task Manager, and BitTorrent wasn't open to begin with.

So, any ideas on what these connections might be for?
I have been using Ad-Aware Free and AVG Free on this computer for a while now, always up to date.

UPDATE:
I ran netstat a few times with different options set, including netstat -a.
Even while I had the network resource monitor open and could see ~5 random IP addresses shown under the System process, netstat showed no connection containing any of these IP addresses.

Another interesting update: Yesterday, while random IPs existed, I downloaded and installed spyboy s&d. The random connections stopped, and I haven't seen them since. This happened before I even scanned using spybot s&d. The 'full scan' showed nothing other than 1 cookie.

Comment: You should install Spyware S&D. Update it, and do a total immunization. That will completely block such connections and provide sufficient protection. AVG should be replaced with Avast free or Avira. Both are MUCH better, perform better, score better. That's all I guess. Maybe you can give an Internet Suite a try (Like Kasperksy Internet Security) , it'll scan your whole network traffic and check for suspicous ones. (A trial version will be enough for a try of course).

Comment: Extra information. Spybot uses your "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" file to block any problematic stuff (can't find better words for this. You can read about how it works on the official homepage or using the in-built help).

Comment: Do you have a NAT router between you and your modem? Can you see if there is similar behaviour on other systems that are connected to the modem/router? Do you have a software firewall running? Can you (once the connections are made) run "netstat -b" (minus quotes) in a command prompt to potentially see what program the connections are coming from? Have you noticed any degradation of the performance of your connection?  Answer as many of these as you can in an edit and I think that will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: If you could supply the details of the addresses and ports and processes, it may help provide a more concise answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a worm which is scanning random IP addresses for potential targets it can spread itself to.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the remote machines trying to connect and gain access to one of your ports. The reason may be genuine and acceptable if you're part of peer network (like Torrent or Tor, etc), otherwise it's just some malicious machines trying to get a backdoor. They'll always pinging the internet for gaining access.

Don't panic!

There's a timeout for such connections and they'll automatically be closed once their grace time is over.

You can use **TCP monitor programs** from TCPView v3.05 which helps you to scrutinize the issue further. Some sites can still have unterminated connections which might vanish after a while.

The situation that needs attention is that you see such a connection or a suspicious IP with status 'LISTENING' or 'ESTABLISHED' on the TCPView. Otherwise, you can see them vanishing one by one or a bunch at a time.

here's more to that,
[image: TCPView]

[TCPView v3.05](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview)

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I use Bitdefender and have Windows 11.

I don't understand what you mean by weird IP address connections. You're asking what these connections are, but give us little information to work with.

If I understand you correctly, you state that ten random IP addresses were sent between 1-500 bytes/sec of information from your computer to remote computers located in the U.S., China, Algeria, Russia, Pakistan, and Korea. You also mention that this exchange took between 1-2 minutes. A quick calculation reveals that 1 minute at 1 byte/second represents 60 bytes (60 seconds * 1) of data was retrieved, and 2 minutes at 500 bytes/second represents 60Kb (120 seconds * 500) of data retrieved. Remote computers appear to be retrieving a very small amount of info from your computer. The info could have been anything, but more often than not there is a legitimate reason for it.

Your hardware, apps, and system might have come from these different countries. For example, the driver used to control your printer might come from any one of these sources and locations. I once bought what I thought was a defective Lexmark printer. After reporting it, I was sent a replacement that came from Pakistan.

Location tells us nothing about the computer resource(s) being affected by these processes. I'd be more interested in knowing what image appears alongside the IP address in Resource Monitor. The network tab is the only place that mentions IP addresses, both local and remote.

Where did you get the time from? Did you time it yourself somehow? This won't work! Though the processes may appear to remain connected for 1-2 minutes, it might take a little time for your system to process the information before Task Manager or Resource Monitor displays that the process has terminated. You might still see it as running even after it ended a short while ago. So, the time it takes also depends on your system and computer's performance. Task Manager or Resource Manager may also have been busy retrieving and processing other data coming from your system and hadn't had the time to update the list, but it will.

A browser doesn't have to be opened for processes to be initiated by local apps, your system, hardware device driver, or a trusted remote computer. Processes are being initiated all the time without you knowing it and run in the background. You might not be using your browser, but this won't prevent the system, apps, or the drivers on your computer from initiating a system, app or driver related process. Even if you turn off or disconnect your modem from the wall outlet, processes might continue to occur when either your system, apps or drivers initiate a process to search for upgrades on the internet. It depends on how these were designed to handle this type of situation.

You used network-tools.com to trace the IP addresses. For lack of a host name it appears you were no closer to obtaining a company name using network-tools.com. Did you know you can Google remote IP addresses by writing it directly in Google's address bar, and it will give you the name of the company and its location. Given this info you can easily Google their site for more info and find the company's physical address. If none of your apps come from them or one of their affiliates, and the process is not system related, then maybe I'd be a little leery with regards to the remote user's intent.

I don't currently have games installed on my computer, yet I have a process called **WildTangent Helper Service** in my list of running processes. I once had a few WildTangent games installed on my computer, but have since uninstalled them. This tells me I have installation components left on my machine that were not removed during the uninstall and that it continues to run a process on my machine for whatever reason. Because the games were uninstalled, the processes associated with WildTangent can't be doing all that much. The files used to initiate these processes are just taking up hard disk space for nothing.